# Create PolygonZ from LineStringZ in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, 3d

Is it possible to create a 3D polygon in pyqgis without using the processing tool LinesToPolygons?

I'm trying to convert a LineStringZ object to a PolygonZ object, but the API only accepts 2D LineStrings or Points. This is despite the API allowing you to create a 3D Point or LineString.

Comment: If you have a layer with `LineStringZ` geometry type you can use the `coerceToType()` method. Link to docs: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a436c092f81cee4590104421c3dd4b1a8  A list comprehension one-liner example: `polyZgeoms = [f.geometry().coerceToType(QgsWkbTypes.PolygonZ)[0] for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]`. Since you have asked about and tagged pyqgis you should post a code snippet showing what you currently have. Not only will this allow us to provide a complete answer, but your question risks being closed without a code attempt.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that has answered the question.

Comment: @BenW Make it an answer plz so it can accepted. Don't want to "steal your thunder" from your answer in the comment

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasG77. No problem, I will post an answer when I  have a chance.